# scanf not responding?

Tags: c

Ive recently begun learning C and am trying to write a password data protection program. Im writing a function which should test to see if a file, password.txt exists if it doesnt it will get a null value and then ask the user to set a master password and to repeat. However it doesnt allow the user to repeat the password. Any tips? - Cheers (Keep in mind just C not C++)

```
/*Headers*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 99

int main(void){

    /*Variable Declaration*/
    char password[] = "Lakaka";

    masterPassword();

    printf("Welcome to Fort-Knox.");

getchar();
return 0;
}

int masterPassword(void){
    /*Password Comparison Variables*/
    char password[MAX_LENGTH];
    char password1[MAX_LENGTH];


    FILE*fp;
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Choose a master password:\n");
        scanf("%c", password);
        printf("Please repeat password:\n");
        scanf("%c", password1);

        if (password == password1){
            printf("Password Accepted.");
            fp = fopen("password.txt", "w+");
            printf("File Created");
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%s` not `%c` as format specifier, when reading a string. `%c` only reads a single character.

Comment: ah OK thanks I though I had to use %c for char as the variable is defined as char. Sorry =(

Answer (score 2):

Your formatting specifier is wrong.

This is also wrong:

```
if (password == password1)
```

this will only compare the arrays converted to pointers. You need to compare character-by-character, by calling `strcmp()`:

```
if( strcmp(password, password1) == 0 )
{
  printf("match!\n");
}
```

Comment: I didn't know I cant compare them like that C is only my second language Python being my first, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `"%s"` instead of `"%c"`

`%c` is for only 1 character

`%s` is for string

```
scanf("%s", password);
scanf("%s", password1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do

```
scanf("%s", password);
```

and to compare use :

```
strncmp(password,password1,MAX_LENGTH)
```

it´s always more safe :)...